# How to apply .htaccess rule for cronjob?

Tags: .htaccess

I am using ZF1 for my application and below is my .htaccess file which is reside in /public folder.

```
.htaccess
----------------------------
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Folder Structure
------------------------------------    
/application
/public
 index.php
/scripts
 cronjob.php
```

Currently, what happen all request redirects to /index.php file. I want /cronjob.php request redirects to **/scripts/cronjob.php** file. How can I do with .htaccess?

Thanks, Jimit

Comment: If the cronjob is running on the same server you don't need any rules for it as it does not use the browser to access the scripts but rather the local path.

Answer (score 0):

Write this rule before index.php redirect rule:

```
RewriteRule ^cronjob.php$ /scripts/cronjob.php [NC,L]
```

rewrite engine will stop execution after L directive, so the user will be redirected to the correct URL.